# Is it safe to ground a portable generator using the house ground at the service panel?

Tags: electrical, grounding, generator

I've bought a portable generator that I'll use when the power goes out. The instructions in the paperwork state that the generator needs to be grounded before use. Can I use the house ground at the service panel to ground the generator?

Comment: First things first -- you have a transfer switch in your house, right?

Comment: Need to ensure your generator is a floating neutral when wiring it directly to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

The generator must get its ground from *whichever* main service panel it feeds (e.g. it could have its own main panel), which in turn must be grounded any way that's legal. If you are simply running extension cords to the generator, it must be grounded legally.

It's legal to share grounds.  You do that by running your own ground strap to the same pipe clamp, pipe or ground rod.  You cannot go inside the other panel.

If generator power is entering the same service panel as utility power, then you absolutely must have some kind of transfer switch, which makes it impossible to have both utility service and generator connected at once.

The transfer switch can be as simple as two 240V breakers with a piece of sliding metal so they can't both be on at the same time.  No big deal. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=panel+transfer+interlock&rls=en&tbm=isch&sa=X

Answer (score 0):

First. Let's just answer your actual question.

> Can I use the house ground at the service panel to ground the generator?

Yes.  You should absolutely do exactly that.

Having an automatic transfer switch is nice.  And a UPS, quaint.  It is substantially important to use your pre-existing house' ground.

For any one building/structure, you must have exactly one, reliable ground.  Do NOT separately ground your generator.  It should tie in to your house' ground the same way any appliance would.

Using a separate ground at the generator can actually be dangerous if there is a nearby lightning strike or a failure of the local electrical utility's infrastructure.

Comment: DON'T downplay the transfer switch.  It's a huge deal.  A mistake here can kill linemen by backfeeding.  It is absolutely mandatory to have a transfer switch (needn't be automatic) or other means to avoid the panel entirely (extension cords, a second service panel going to purple outlets all over the house, whatever).

Comment: If you employ a transfer switch that breaks the neutral you MUST drive a separate ground rod for the generator. Otherwise, if the generator has a bonding jumper tying the neutral and ground together that has to be removed while it is connected to the house. It should be grounded through the 4 wire cable feeding the house.

Answer (score -3):

dont know where you are but in scotland we dont have transfer switches,but i use a generater for the same reason mines is prob smaller and I move it from room to room so what i have done is put an earth wire from the machine and wired it to the earth pin in the plug so i just plug it into any socket and thats it earthed via the house supply.Dont know what type of socket you have but hope this helps.

best regards john

Comment: Don't ever use a generator inside your home - it's a gasoline combustion appliance and needs to be ventilated. Using a generator indoors can poison and kill you.